# Does anyone know how to implement simple mouse gestures in jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, gestures

Something exactly like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmS6RD31DE8) would be perfect.

Comment: Please post what you've tried, show that you've made some effort other than seeing a feature in a youtube video. I will remove my -1 when you put a little more effort into your question.

Comment: Well, I was assuming that there was a plugin that I couldn't find. I found that jQuery plugin that Clive mentioned. But there was nothing to download. I looked at a few others too but they were far too obtrusive.

Comment: After watching that youtube video I question the utility of this.  A mouse is a poor device to use for inputting gestures.  Cursor-driven input and touch-driven input are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JQuery mouse gestures plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/mouse-gesture) would be a good place to start.

Downloads page is [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/3741/release)

Comment: Comments from the downvoter would be appreciated...what's the problem with this plugin?

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I can't seem to find a place to download it. EDIT: I didn't downvote that.

Comment: No worries didn't think you would have! You can download the plugin here: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/3741/release. If it does the trick do me a favour and accept this answer so others will know it's correct and can ignore the downvoter.